# How to close the Azure ServiceBus QueueClient gracefully?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

When I call `QueueClient.Close()`, it always raises an exception:

> The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed
>   or aborted.

It raises the exception, even if the queue was empty.

Although I handle it by using `OnMessageOptions.ExceptionReceived`, but it's annoying me. Is there something wrong with my code?

**How to stop the QueueClient gracefully?**

[Start, and stop the messaging]

```
// create a QueueClient with Exception handler.
var queueClient = queueManager.GetStorage<UpdateTriggerQueueClient>();
var options = new OnMessageOptions
{
    AutoComplete = false
};
// When the Close() called, it always handles an exception.
options.ExceptionReceived += (sender, args) => 
    logger.Error("An excepion occurred.", args.Exception);

// prepare a CancellationTokenSource.
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

// start message pump.
queueClient.OnMessageAsync(async message => 
            await DoWork(message, cancellationToken), options);

// sometime after, stop(cancel) the work.
Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

// some code to wait every in-progress messages finished.
// ...

// close the client.
queueClient.Close();
```

[DoWork method]

```
private async Task DoWork(BrokeredMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    logger.Trace("begin work");
    // Do something cancellable work.
    await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(async t =>
        {
            // complete the message when the task completed,
            // otherwise, abandon the message.
            if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                await message.CompleteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await message.AbandonAsync();
            }
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // cleanup
            logger.Trace("end work");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop all messages from being recieved by updating the subscription with:

```
_namespaceManager.UpdateSubscription(new SubscriptionDescription(_strTopic, _strSubscription) 
  { 
     Status = EntityStatus.ReceiveDisabled
  });
```

This may solve your problem even though it's not exactly what you're asking. (I'm also trying to find out how to close() properly.

You will also need to update the status to begin receiving again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to understand how the IQueueClient interface works. When you receive a message you receive what is called a CancellationToken. The CancellationToken enables you to cooperate a cancellation between threads, thread pool work items, or Task object. In this case you need to handle Azure Service Bus connection. This is what I will do, control if the connection has been closed, if that is the case, I will check if the message we have received still alive.

```
public async Task<object> ReceiveAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
            //If the connection still open, we do something
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
             ...
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I read on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh528527.aspx that close should not be called as the connection is managed by the message factories.

```
this.mSubscriptionClient.OnMessage(
             (pMessage) =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     // Will block the current thread if Stop is called.
                     this.mPauseProcessingEvent.WaitOne();

                     // Execute processing task here
                     pProcessMessageTask(pMessage);
                 }
                 catch(Exception ex)
                 {
                     this.RaiseOnLogMessageEvent(pMessage, ex);
                 }
             },
             options);
```

And then when you are ready to stop

```
this.mPauseProcessingEvent.Reset();
mSubscriptionClient.Close();
```

The datatype is

```
private ManualResetEvent mPauseProcessingEvent;
```

Comment: I called `Close` method because I need to stop receiving message on the QueueClient. Can you explain me how to stop receiving messages without calling `Close`?

Comment: The page linked to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh528527.aspx says "You should not close messaging factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then re-create them when you send the next message." So it's talking about closing and recreating the client each time you want to process a message, and not about when you want to close the client because you're done for good.